# How to get data from RAID1 with Windows PC?

Tags: windows-10, raid, nas, raid-1

### Is it possible to recover RAID 1 data with a Windows PC?

My ZYXEL NAS326 died, but both 4TB hard drives are still good.

I found this question:

[Recovering data from RAID1 drive](https://superuser.com/questions/455889)

But it is for running on a Ubuntu system. I am very illiterate when it comes to Linux systems.

I also found a [ZYXEL Support Article](https://kb.zyxel.com/KB/searchArticle!gwsViewDetail.action?articleOid=013308&lang=EN) that says to use a Linux PC. In the absence of a Linux PC, simply use a second ZYXEL NAS to read the data from the first ZYXEL NAS. I really don't want to give them more of my money when I have one of their NAS devices that just died on me.

Comment: A modern version of Ubuntu will probably pick up the RAID automatically. It's also very user-friendly and doesn't require installation. It's worth giving it a try - you probably won't spend more time figuring it out than setting up Linux RAID on Windows.

Comment: @gronostaj is there a site for a free download? I tried it before, but I can't even figure out basic stuff like pulling up Notepad or starting the FTP server. When I asked in forums, all I would get were smartass answers that were not even correct.

Comment: Just google it, ubuntu.com will be the first result. You couldn't find Notepad because Notepad is the name of Microsoft's text editor for Windows - looking for a text editor would turn up Gedit which is installed by default. Starting an FTP server is definitely not basic stuff.

Comment: RAID1 should not be difficult at all, it's mostly like recovering from a single drive.

Answer (score 1):

If the controller died but the disks are in good shape, you have a good chance
of recovering your data using one of the many available
[recovery products](https://recoverit.wondershare.com/harddrive-recovery/top-5-raid-hard-drive-data-recovery.html?keywords=Videospiel&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI8NCz1Jy67QIVy56zCh2MRQliEAAYAyAAEgLopPD_BwE).

The problem is that most recovery products are costly. They usually offer a free trial
version, but do not disclose the limits of this version.

The above linked article describes DiskInternals, GetDataBack,
ReclaiMe Free RAID recovery and Zero Assumption Recovery.
But there are others like
[Wondershare](https://recoverit.wondershare.com/free-data-recovery/free-raid-recovery.html)
and
[MiniTool](https://www.minitool.com/data-recovery/raid-recovery-software.html).

You will need to try the trial versions, see how effective they are and what are
their limits, then decide on your preferred product.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen a few. Free to try and download, but then they want $200 to $400 to unlock their data recovery features. Seems like bait-and-switch. I could buy a new NAS and just drop my drives in for that kind of cash.

Comment: I put the old drives in the new NAS and they worked like they were supposed to\